# Creating multi-language pages in Google Sites

Tags: multilingual, google-sites

is it possible to create pages in more than one language without having to create separate pages for each language in Google Sites?

This isn't a feature of Google Sites, but I was hoping there might be a workaround.

Greets,
Kenny

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using JavaScript. If you're looking for automatic translation you can try the [Google Translate Widget](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools).

If you're going to do the translation yourself you could create a language dropdown and use JS to replace the page's contents with the contents of the selected language. To do this though (assuming Google Sites doesn't allow you to use server-side code; not really sure) you'd have to have the browser download the page in all languages then just use JS to swap in the correct content.

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dosboy/bJtGw/) to see what I mean.

Comment: Google Translate is built-in in Classic Google Sites.

Answer (score 0):

The Classic Google Sites automatically adds a "Translate" button at the bottom of the page.

[image]

It's worthy to note that the languange settings of your account / web browser could prevent to show it, so if you want to test this feature use a different account and browser set in a language different from your site.

For the above screenshot, my site is in Spanish, the test account and web browser language are set to English.